# How to open a list of images from an asset as an Image Collection?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, list

I need to create an Image collection from a list of images that I import from an asset in GEE. This is the code I am using:

```
//THE CREATION OF A IMAGECOLLECTION WORKS WITH TWO IMAGES LOADED HERE
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection(image3).merge(ee.ImageCollection(image4))
print(imageCollection)

//OPEN AN IMAGE ASSET AS A LIST
var assetList = ee.List(ee.data.getList({'id':"users/anabsantos15/teste"}))
print("Size list:",ee.List(assetList.getInfo()).size())
var list = ee.List(assetList.getInfo())

//CREATE A IMAGE COLLECTION FROM A LIST OF IMAGES
var make_collection = ee.ImageCollection(list)
print(make_collection)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ImageCollection (Error)
ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type.
Expected type: List<Image<unknown bands>>.
Actual type: List<Dictionary<Object>>.
Actual value: [{id=users/anabsantos15/teste/20200116_122201_0f46_3B_AnalyticMS_SR_clip, type=Image, properties={}}, {id=users/anabsantos15/teste/20200316_125118_1025_3B_AnalyticMS_SR_clip, type=Image, properties={}}]
```

which I have no clue on how to interpret.

Which steps can I take to load those images as an ImageCollection?

Here is the link to the working code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/35adf288f269421ef6a27f56b359e1b6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getList` doesn't return a list of names, it returns a list of dictionaries.  You need to map over the result to get out the names as a list.
Also, don't use listAssets, it's deprecated.
Also, don't use getInfo.

```
var assetList = ee.data.listAssets("users/anabsantos15/teste")['assets']
                    .map(function(d) { return d.name })
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(assetList)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/91f24194dcfce509bade75fd37c070c8

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked as intended!